# Python how to change dataframe format

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, transpose

Could you please help how to transpose the dataframe:

From this:

```
data = {'ID' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
        'Name' : ['OO', 'XX', 'YY','ZZ', 'MM', 'VV', 'RR'],
         'Rank' : [5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
         'Price' : [20,30,40,50,60,70,80]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   ID Name Rank Price
0   1   OO  5   20
1   1   XX  6   30
2   1   YY  7   40
3   2   ZZ  8   50
4   2   MM  9   60
5   2   VV  10  70
6   2   RR  11  80
```

To this

[image]

Note, I have a huge excel file for this, this is just a sample.

Comment: Do you really want to have repeated column names?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma yes, if you know how to do it, what would be the other option 'Rank1',Name1','Price1',Rank2'...? I prefer with the columns repeated

Comment: IMO repeated column names will be of no use(unless there is a good reason). I prefer having the unique identifier on each column names.

Comment: @Shubham Sharma alright, then adding numbers like I wrote : 'Rank_1',Name_1','Price_1',Rank_2','Name_2',... would also be fine

Comment: Check Q10. of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately, it's not what I need, he put column A into the header, I wnt the headers to stay as they are or add some numbers to it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` + `cumcount` add a sequential counter `cols` to the dataframe, then reshape using `pivot` keeping `ID` as index and `cols` as the new columns. After reshaping sort the columns on `level=1` to maintain the order, finally flatten the columns using `map` with `format`

```
df['cols'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1
s = df.pivot('ID', 'cols').sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
s.columns = s.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

---

```
   Name_1  Price_1  Rank_1 Name_2  Price_2  Rank_2 Name_3  Price_3  Rank_3 Name_4  Price_4  Rank_4
ID                                                                                                
1      OO     20.0     5.0     XX     30.0     6.0     YY     40.0     7.0    NaN      NaN     NaN
2      ZZ     50.0     8.0     MM     60.0     9.0     VV     70.0    10.0     RR     80.0    11.0
```

Comment: @skittles-brah Does this answered your question?